# FillEllipse, DrawEllipse, drawing inside

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, paint, ellipse

I used methods to paint this figure, as follows:

```
g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(this.EllipseColor), bounds);

g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(this.ForeColor), bounds);
```

However I'm interested in if there's any possibility to paint inside of this figure, e.g sign of "cross" or so with mentioned methods.

Thank in adavance!

[image]

Comment: Explain 'draw'! Do you mean by code of by user interaction? You can code with many DrawXXX methods. And you can let your user draw by collecting mousepositions in a movemove event and using DrawCurve to draw them e.g. in the  Paint event. You can also use Graphics.SetClip to restrict drawing to a shape.

Comment: I meant by code. I used two methods to fill an ellipse and to draw an ellipse. For example how can I draw within the 'white' field one  more figure e.g. cross.

Comment: You can draw two lines, no? All drawing stack onto the pixel on the control/form surface, so order matters..

Comment: What's method that allows to draw lines? ) Give a suggest!

Comment: Do look into all the DrawXXX methods of the [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class!! Here is is DrawLine.. Btw: I hope you draw in the Paint event as you should!

Comment: protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)                              OK! I'll take a look!

Comment: Good! Example: `using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Bisque, 5f))
{
    g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Left + 10, bounds.Height / 2, bounds.Right - 10, bounds.Height/2);
    g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Top + 10, bounds.Width/2, bounds.Bottom - 10);
}`

Comment: Is this within "white " field of my "circle"? And one more thing. How do I rate you suggests?) Have no idea.

Comment: This should draw inside the ellipse. Comments can ve upvoted to do not earn reputation. No problem.. If you meant how to restrict drawing look into GraphicsPath (in Drawing2D) and SetClip..!

Comment: However, more complicate figures e.g. diagonal lines, there should be used another method. Don't it?

Comment: No, these are not more complicated, just use the right coordinates! - There are plenty of methods for really more complicated shapes like arcs, bezier curves or polygons, though..

Comment: I managed to draw a triangle inside of circle (6 coordinates). But It does not change its size... as desired. I mean the same way as circle.

Comment: To change the size you must change the data. Let me guess: `bounds` was the ClientRectangle of the Form, so it was changed when Resizing. If you want a similar effect your 6 coordinates must also depend on the form size like my crossed lines did..